# IntelliJ IDEA - Choosing specific font width within family

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, editor

I'm on OS X El Capitan running IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3.

I've been trying to change the font in my IntelliJ IDEA editor, but when I go to select which font to select, the dropdown list only gives me a list of font families, and doesn't allow me to choose individual weights, as I wanted to use the Book font, while IntelliJ uses the Medium font by default. Is there any way to prioritize which weight I want to use?

I found an indirect way by disabling the Medium font file through Font Book, but that kind of bothers me because that disables it for all programs rather than simply IntelliJ.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible now. I just checked by going to *Settings > Editor > Font* and different font weights show up correctly in the dropdown:

[image]

If you still have this problem, you should [file an issue with JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues).